# Nexus One USB freezes Vista SP2 Quad Core

Tags: usb, freeze, eclipse, android

My Nexus One (N1) will occasionally freeze my Vista 32bit SP2 Quad Core 2.4GHz during POST.  MB is ASUS P5N-E SLI with 4GB of RAM.

The PC will be booting and when I connect the N1 via USB, the boot sequence will freeze, then continue once I unplug the N1 USB link.

It happens whether the N1 is in USB debugging mode and when it is not.

I'm not sure whether this is an N1 hw/fw issue, system interaction with my PC, or a result of my N1 development environment (I'm using the Eclipse Galileo IDE for Java Developers, primarily compiling to API Level 7.  Eclipse has also occasionally frozen although I haven't established N1 USB cause-and-effect on that issue).

Is anyone else experiencing these symptom?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SuperUser. You question has been migrated to this site, where it is more suited. Consider creating an account here, and linking it to your StackOverflow account (in user options), in order to retrieve ownership on the question.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me every time I attempt to reboot my PC with either my G1 or my Nexus One plugged into the USB port.  It's because the BIOS is trying to check if it should boot off the external USB drive it has detected, but since the SD card isn't mounted so the PC can actually read the contents of it the PC just hangs.  It always finishes booting as soon as I unplug the phone from the USB.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.  Changed my boot sequence to disable removable drives in the priority - still froze.  Mounting the N1 SD during boot didn't help either.  I guess I'll just have to stop using USB to recharge my N1.  Iphone doesn't behave this way.

Side note: what forum do you suggest this question belongs in?  from where I seat, this forum worked great since I got a reasonable answer from you.

Comment: 1.  I made the comment about it not belonging on stackoverflow.com, where you originally posted the question.  Notice how it got migrated to superuser.com?  

2.  Why are you rebooting your computer so much that this is an issue?

3.  Please refrain from comparing your Nexus One to your iPhone as if the Android should work identically to an iPhone.  Android phones use a different external USB drive protocol, among many other differences.

Comment: For what it's worth I've experienced this same problem where my PC tries to boot from my 5th Generation iPod or my HTC Hero if I have either of them plugged in during start up. I'm also pretty sure it used to do this with my iPhone 3G but I couldn't swear to that. I've just learned to plug anything in after Windows 7 has commenced loading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact problem might be, as I don't own a Nexus One, but if the N1 contains what looks like a bootable file partition and your computer's boot sequence is set to boot external drives before internal ones, this could cause it to hang. It's also possible if the N1 has a slightly powered USB port, that the feedback from the USB can stop your computer from booting.

Comment: Thanks.  My boot sequence indeed starts with "removable" media, but disabling that did not stop the freezing.  The N1 can be recharged by the PC USB port - how can I test your hypothesis about the feedback potentially stopping the boot?  Over the years, I've had other USB devices that freeze the boot (eg a Polar IR transmitter) but I've never bothered to troubleshoot beyond identifying the culprit and unpluggging it.